# UIStoryboard segue which deallocs old UIVIewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to connect two `UIViewControllers` with a segue which completely replaces the old `UIViewControllers`. I will not be needing the previous ones any more so I would like them to be deallocated to save memory, but if I use a modal segue they are still there. How can I use segues to make sure the new `UIViewController` replaces all the previous ones?

The reason I want this is for a register screen. The user goes through the registration process and once finished goes into the main part of the app. All the registration `UIViewControllers` are not needed any more so I would like them to be deallocated. However If I use a segue for this (like a modal segue) the views are still there (as they could be seen again if I used dismissViewController).

Note: I know how to do this programmatically, I am looking for a way to do this with segues.

Answer (score 1):

Since your registration process is presumably used infrequently (once when the user first installs and perhaps again if they want to register as a new user for some reason) it probably makes most sense to have your main screen as the root view and then present your registration screens from that when needed.  Once you have completed the registration process you can simply unwind back to your main screen, releasing the registration controller(s)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do that is:

```
// in your UIStoryboardSegue subclass

-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *src = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dest = self.destinationViewController;
    [src presentViewController:dest animated:YES completion:^{
        dest.view.window.rootViewController = dest;
    }];
}
```